# Folium and MarkerCluster?

Tags: leaflet, folium, ipython

I'm trying to use [Folium](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium) but am having difficulty adding multiple points to a MarkerCluster in one fell swoop.  Documentation is... sparse, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

This recreates the problem in an IPython notebook:

```py
import folium print folium.__version__
# __version__ == 0.2.1

Joburg=[-26.2041, 28.0473]
locations=[[-26.15048, 28.10404],  [-28.67343, 32.1051],  [-25.97249, 28.12367]]

# Adding the markers one-by-one works fine:
map1 = folium.Map(location=Joburg,zoom_start=9)
my_marker_cluster1 = folium.MarkerCluster()
for location in locations:
    folium.Marker(location=location).add_to(my_marker_cluster1)
map1.add_children(my_marker_cluster1)

# Adding them together fails (i.e., the map renders, but with no markers on it)
map2 = folium.Map(location=Joburg,zoom_start=9)
my_marker_cluster2 = folium.MarkerCluster(locations)
map2.add_children(my_marker_cluster2)
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>In your first case, you're adding `Marker` objects iteratively to your `MarkerCluster`. In the second case, you are just giving a list of coordinates, but not `Marker` objects. Convert your `locations` list first:</strike>

```
locations = [folium.Marker(l) for l in locations]
```

This is incorrect advice, see comment and the [MarkerCluster source](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/5c5c0d6845c519d1383072e351770a9c2a0808e1/folium/plugins/marker_cluster.py#L16).

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem to work for me.  (Same problem-- markers don't render.)  Moreover, if I use `heatmap_map.add_children(plugins.HeatMap(locations))` (where `locations` is a list of coordinates rather than `Marker` objects), it *does* work.  (But maybe the API is just inconsistent?)

Comment: Actually, I was only assuming that that was your problem, without checking the Folium API. Indeed, your example should work, as `MarkerCluster` says that it takes a list of a list or array of shape (n,2), e.g. `[[lat,lon]]`. You probably have some other problem.

Comment: If you run the sample code, does it work for you?  That would help me understand where the "other problem" might be.